# Python Pandas: use row number in apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am only beginning with Pandas and I am stuck with the following problem:
I want to use the row number in df.apply() so that it calculates (1+0.05)^(row_number), ex:
(1+0.05)^0 in its first row, (1+0.05)^1 in its second, (1+0.05)^2 in its third etc....

I tried the following but get AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'

```
import pandas as pd

considered_period_years = 60
start_year = 2019
TDE = 0.02
year = list(range(start_year,start_year+considered_period_years))

df = pd.DataFrame(year, columns = ['Year'])
df.insert(0, 'Year Number', range(0,60), allow_duplicates = False)
df.insert(2, 'Investition', 0, allow_duplicates = False)

df['Investition2'] = df['Investition'].apply(lambda x: x*(1+TDE)**x.name)
```

Any ideas ?

Regards Johann

Comment: Do you want to use the **index**, or the **row number/position**? Also, why are you using `insert` to add the columns, instead of doing so when you create the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to pandas. Familiarize yourself with *vectorized* functions. The basic idea behind vectorized functions is that you apply the operation to every element in an array without an explicit loop. For example:

```
x + 1
```

means "add 1 to element in `x`".

Similarly:

```
x * y
```

means "multiply every element in `x` by every element in `y`, pair-wise".

Deep down, vectorized functions are implemented using highly-optimized C loops so they are both fast and convenient.

In your case:

```
df['Investition2'] = (1+TDE)**df.index
```

Comment: The index is _not_ the same thing as the row number.

Comment: The index is not always the same thing as row number, but in this case it is

Answer (score -2):

- You can create a custom function (`foo` in our case) to access `row.name` since you are using `df['Investitions2']` it's giving you a Series. And `apply` series will iterate through its values.

```
import pandas as pd

considered_period_years = 60
start_year = 2019
TDE = 0.02
year = list(range(start_year,start_year+considered_period_years))

df = pd.DataFrame(year, columns = ['Year'])
df.insert(0, 'Year Number', range(0,60), allow_duplicates = False)
df.insert(2, 'Investition', 0, allow_duplicates = False)

def foo(row):
    return row['Investition']*(1+TDE)**row.name

df['Investition2'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x), axis=1)
```

- Another alternative is to use `itertuples` or `iterrows`.

Comment: `iterrows` is pretty terrible, I would strongly recommend `itertuples` instead.